# Swagger defined API can not be executed locally on Serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

When api specification of serverless.yml is described in swagger format in `resources` instead of `functions` , API can not be executed locally.

1. API specification of serverless.yml is described in swagger format in `resources`

serverless.yml is below.

```
functions:                                                                                                                                   
    test:                                                                                                                                      
      handler: test.test                                                                                                                      

resources:                                                                                                                                   
  Resources:                                                                                                                                 
    RestApi :                                                                                                                                
      Type : AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi                                                                                                        
      Properties :                                                                                                                           
        Body : ${file(./swagger.yaml)}
```

The result of `sls offline` does not have routes for test API.

```
Serverless: Starting Offline: dev/ap-northeast-1.

Serverless: Routes for test:
Serverless: (none)

Serverless: Offline listening on http://localhost:3000
```

2. API specification of serverless.yml is described in swagger format in `functions`
   serverless.yml is below.

```
functions:
  test:
    handler: test.test
    events:
      - http: GET test

#resources:
#  Resources:
#    RestApi :
#      Type : AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
#      Properties :
#        Body : ${file(./swagger.yaml)}
```

The result of `sls offline` have routes for test API.

```
Serverless: Starting Offline: dev/ap-northeast-1.

Serverless: Routes for test:
Serverless: GET /test

Serverless: Offline listening on http://localhost:3000
```

I want to run the API locally by describing specifications in swagger format in resources. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `serverless-offline` plugin understands the serverless landscape, but does not understand custom AWS resources. Its also unlikely to in the future as serverless is an abstraction layer.

Perhaps [aws-sam-cli](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli) would be a better fit for your application. It seems to support swagger docs and a local environment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try AWS SAM on next project!